# PHP Array with Private Vars

Tags: php

How i can read this array alone $var['shipment_number'] don't work?

```
EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response Object
(
    [shipment_number:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response:private] => 222253010000075775
    [piece_number:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response:private] =>
    [label:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response:private] => https://cig.Einurl.com
    [returnLabel:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response:private] =>
    [exportDoc:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response:private] =>
    [labelType:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response:private] => URL
    [sequenceNumber:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response:private] => 1
    [statusCode:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response:private] => 0
    [statusText:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response:private] => ok
    [statusMessage:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response:private] => Der Webservice wurde ohne Fehler ausgeführt.
    [version:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Version:private] => 2.2
    [mayor:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Version:private] => 2
    [minor:EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Version:private] => 2
)
```

Code link:
https://pastebin.com/uDm6neRt

Comment: That's an object, not array. You can try `$var->getShipmentNumber()` to see if it works.

Comment: [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) !== [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is an [object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), specifically an instance of `EinName\EINUNTERNEHMEN\Response`. Further, the properties are `private`, so you can only access them directly from inside the class.

See this example:

```
<?php
class Response {
    private $var;

    public function __construct($var) {
        $this->var = $var;
    }

    public function getVar() {
        return $this->var;
    }
}
$res = new Response("test");
echo $res->getVar(); // test
echo $res->var; // fatal error, attempting to access a private property
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/QfElo)

So, if you don't have access to the class, to get the properties you need to use the getter, if it exists. Check the documentation of your `Response` class, by convention it should look like this:

```
echo $var->getShipmentNumber();
```